# Aws lambda function connect to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function which connects to database and find user.

```
import pymongo

def my_handler(event, context):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('uri') #My db connection here. 
    db = client.dbName
    col = db.users
    col.find_one({'email':'example@gmail.com'})
    foundedUser = col.find_one({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'})
    print(foundedUser)
    client.close()
```

I got a weird problem, sometimes lambda connects and find user like for 100ms or even less.
But sometimes there is a timed out error after 30 sec.
I have all vpc configs and so on.
I've tried to make it using node.js and now trying with python result is the same.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: I can not see a lambda function on the code above.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos Added function definition.
What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean AWS Lambda function.
I connect to my db inside AWS lambda function, like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html

Comment: It might be a network issue. While configuring Lambda you can provide VPC detail, this network configuration may contain subnets with connection to DocumentDB and that connection is blocked to DocumentDB. So if Lambda function is invoked from a subnet with connection enabled, your Lambda works fine. Otherwise if Lambda is invoked from a blocked network segment, you might be waiting for connection timeout. Please check https://www.kodyaz.com/aws/connect-amazon-documentdb-using-python-from-aws-lambda-function.aspx for additional considerations on connection to DocumentDB from Lambda function

Answer (score 1):

So I was running into the same issue. Check these out.

https://blog.cloudboost.io/i-wish-i-knew-how-to-use-mongodb-connection-in-aws-lambda-f91cd2694ae5

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs

and this

https://hackernoon.com/building-a-serverless-rest-api-with-node-js-and-mongodb-2e0ed0638f47

Apparently, AWS Lambda is "stateless" and the way that I understand it, once the function is called on a cold start it runs your code and connects to your database. After that, any call you make to your Lambda function for a certain time (say 5 minutes) will use that same connection. Afterwards, if the connection is closed and a function is invoked again, the Lamda doesn't reestablish a connection to the database.

The tutorials should hopefully help set it up so that it checks for a connection on each function call.